# App Fabric One Reliable Actor for One Node Partitioning

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

We have ActorService which creates several actors based on unique devices. The actor sends a command to device based on profiles.

We used to send commands to device by webjob, but we decided yo use reliable actors to send commands to devices.

The Challenge is now, each node in actor service a separate actor is created. For ex. 3 nodes are created that means 3 different actors for 
"One device" are created.

Now I am not sure which actor is being executed at what time and I do want only one actor to send command to device instead of three.

How can I partition a actor uniquely for each node?

Comment: can you not just give each device/node a device id and use that for a relay actor to send the data back to the device?

Comment: @KevinSmith : We would be glad to know how to do that. Can you please suggest some samples or guide me in right direction?

Comment: You could just use a static id for the actor which is sending data back to the devices, alternatively just use a standard service fabric service. I've not really seen any examples around doing it though.